# Modeling (foreign keys) in Django

Tags: django

**Use Case:**

- Upon Registration a user has to select his company (not ideal but ok)
- the company is stored in his UserProfile
- The car model and car type have a foreignKey to company
- Upon display only cars and cartypes created by the company of the user, shall be displayed to the user.

**Modeling:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company             = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class Car(models.Model):
    model_name          = models.CharField(_(u"Model Name"))
    car_type            = models.CharField(_(u"Car Type"))
    company             = models.ForeignKey(Company)

class CarType(models.Model):
    car_type = models.CharField(_(u"Car Type"))
    company      = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

**View:**

```
def main_page_view(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    AllCarsCreatedByTheCompany = profile.company.car_set.all()
```

This works already perfect, however the problem is the CarType.

**Problem:**

-Each company produces different car types. And thank to the company foreignkey, its already separated from another company.

- Upon Adding a new car the user shall choose from the dropdown only the car types that his company has explicitly created, however in this case the user sees all the car_types, even the ones not created by his company.

**What I have done:**

```
def new_car_view(request):
    profile = request.user.get_profile()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CarForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            car = Car.objects.create(
                model_name=form.cleaned_data['model_name'],
                company=profile.company
            )
            car.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = CarForm()
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form':form})
    return render_to_response('car_add.html', variables)
```

**Form:**

```
class CarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        exclude = ('company')
```

However the form shows all car types in the dropdown instead of the ones filtered by the company foreign key. What am I missing please?

Comment: You've cut down your example too much: you don't have any reference to car type in the Car model or form. How are you displaying that dropdown?

Comment: @DanielRoseman apologies, you are right. I have just updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to modify the selection in the init. Here is an example:

```
class CarForm(forms.ModelForm):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(CarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # limit selection list to just items for this account
    self.fields['cartypes'].queryset = CarType(company=company)
```

Also, include company as a hidden field so you can reference it rather than excluding it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am passing from view `form = CarForm(profile.company)`  and in CarForm you had a typo I think: `self.fields['car_type'].queryset = CarType(company=args)`  however it says now `Cannot assign "(<Company: Mercedes Ltd>,)": "CarType.company" must be a "Company" instance.`  But according to debugger it is a company...sorry I am new to Django might miss something very obvious

Comment: This should be `...queryset = CarType.objects.filter(company=company)`.